# C# WinForm single mouse move event beneath controls

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I'm creating C# WinForm application and want to hook mouse move event that beneath child controls. <del>Found one solution but required to hook every control's mouse move event and my child controls also have its own mouse move event</del>. So is it possible to hook mouse move event beneath controls with single event hook

Comment: you can hook to event for multiple times, so what's wrong with solution you find?

Comment: i actually want single event hook if it is possible

Comment: So what. You can attach as much handlers to single event as you need.

Comment: Could you attach link to what you found or example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719636/how-to-capture-mousemove-events-beneath-child-controls   Difference is that the i want single event hook.